# Item validating and set formatting

Tags: python

I will explain the behavior of my code

1. You enter the file name and the item name.
2. It will display the name of the item and the quantity from the line in the list.

First problem: Actually, I want it to display the second item in the list and tell that's it's a duplicate. At the moment, if I remove list(set() I will get 2 bananas output separately in the same string.

example of .txt file I am importing.

```
bananes: 18
pommes: 23
bananes: 13
```

example of .txt file I am importing.

```
pommes : 54
: 18
banane:

oranges : 30
```

example of input:

```
item.py data10.txt bananes
```

example of needed output:

```
La ligne banane : 13 est un doublon.
```

output I am getting:

```
La ligne ['1', 's', ' ', 'e', ',', "'", '8', 'n', ':', 'b', '2', 'a'] est un doublon.
```

---

Second problem: This works fine if I write any other word than a word that is in the list. But actually if I write a few first letters of the word it'll still display the line completely.

example of input:

```
item.py data10.txt pomm
```

example of needed output:

```
pomm: 0
```

Output I am getting:

```
pomme: 30
```

Here's my code so you can have an idea of what I do:

```
import sys

def ligne(texte):
    try:
        with open(texte) as ouvrir:
            lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
            words = [" : ".join([x.strip() for x in line.split(":")]) for line in lecture]
            words = [x for x in words if len(x) > 1]
            return words
    except IOError:
        print("Le fichier", texte, "n'existe pas.")
        sys.exit()

def recherche(essaie):
    while True:
        if len(essaie) > 3:
            print("Deux arguments sont attendus, le nom du fichier d'inventaire et l'item")
            sys.exit()
        elif len(essaie) < 3:
            print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier et de l'item.")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            entree = essaie[1]
            item = essaie[2]
            choix = str(entree)
            texte = choix.strip("[']")
            resultat = [s for s in ligne(texte) if item in s]
            resultat2 = str(resultat)
            longueur = len(resultat)
            resultat3 = resultat2.strip("[']")
            resultat4 = list(set(resultat3))
            if item in str(ligne(texte)):
                if longueur > 1:
                    print("La ligne", resultat4, "est un doublon.")
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print(resultat3)
                    sys.exit()
            else:
                print(item, ": 0")
                sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recherche(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I have tried a lot of things to try to fix these problem without success

Comment: Each item in `item in str(ligne(texte))` will be a single character of the representation of the list returned by `ligne()`, which is not what you want. There a similar problem with `resultat4 = list(set(resultat3))` because `resultat3` is a string, so a creating a set from it results in the set of characters in the string, which is then converted to the list you are seeing being printed out. I guess the important point is that in Python strings are sequences, are iterable, and therefore can be confused with lists.

Comment: i didnt understand how to apply your recommendation to my code i am sorry

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to accomplish by your last two edits as it just make your question harder to understand. Regardless, sorry, but in my opinion your whole approach to doing this processing is a poor one—and not worth trying to unravel and fix. Instead I suggest you read the data file into a dictionary as suggested in @slearner's answer.

Comment: yes thanks i am working on making slearner code working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using a dictionary for this problem rather than the list/set of strings. You can read in the lines as key/value pairs and then check if a key is already in the dictionary. If so, it's a duplicate and raise an exception (if you like, you can substitute this for a printed string and a sys.exit(0).

Check the sample code below...

```
import sys

def ligne(texte, item):
    try:
        with open(texte) as ouvrir:
            words_dict = {} #Create new, empty dictionary
            lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
            for line in lecture: #For each line in .txt file
                line = line.strip('\n')
                key, number = line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1]) #Item is before ':', value is after
                if key not in words_dict.keys(): 
                    words_dict[key] = number #If that item isn't in the dictionary yet (this is the first occurence), add it
                elif key == item: #If the duplicate is the inputed item
                    raise Exception('La ligne {} est un doublon.'.format(line)) #If that item is already in the dictionary, raise an exception
            return words_dict #If there are no duplicates, the dictionary will be returned, if there are, it will return the error above
    except IOError:
        print("Le fichier", texte, "n'existe pas.")
        sys.exit()

def recherche(essaie):
    if len(essaie) > 3:
        print("Deux arguments sont attendus, le nom du fichier d'inventaire et l'item")
        sys.exit()
    elif len(essaie) < 3:
        print("Il faut preciser le nom du fichier et de l'item.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        entree = essaie[1]
        item = essaie[2]

        choix = str(entree)
        texte = choix.strip("[']")
        resultat_dict = ligne(texte, item) #If this returns without raising an exception, there were no duplicates

        if item in resultat_dict.keys():
            print item, ": {}".format(resultat_dict[item]) #If the item was in the .txt file, print it and its value
        else:
            print item, ": 0" #If not, print with a value of zero

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recherche(sys.argv)
```

I tried to leave comments to explain all the changes, but let me know if anything is unclear. The key changes are reading the file into a dictionary and raising an exception if a duplicate is found, but I did as much as a I could to keep the structure of your original code intact (though there may be simpler ways/more efficient ways to go about this). The last part of the recherche function also gets much simpler that way, as you know that if ligne returns without an error, there are no duplicates.

Comment: The program output someting if there's a duplicated but its not working like i mentionned in the question. Also it is not working if i enter the word pommes as an exemple, it will output 0 even if its in the list. try with a list that doesnt contain duplicated. i am studying your answer and will try to figure it out. if you have any queue it would help!

Comment: Hmm, what's the .txt file you're using with it? It's working on my end with 'pommes' as an input, what is it returning when you try it?

Comment: i get an out of range some time     key, number = line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range and all other results i get if i try an other file with other items are equal 0 because i have files that looks like i just added in my question

Comment: i have added an exemple of a lis tnot working and it's giving out this error. i guess have to add all these exeptions in the line(texte, item) ??

Comment: Yeah if a line isn't formatted with "item: number" then `key, number = line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1])` will throw an IndexError. So you have two choices 1) don't feed it a txt file that's not formatted correctly or 2) ignore lines that aren't formatted correctly. You can do the second by adding a `try, except` around the line that splits the key and value and then just passing over lines that don't fit the correct format. That would look like this:

`try:
    key, number = line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1])
except IndexError:
    continue`

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer i keep on working on this!!